# Como obtener length de un json

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un problema al tratar de recorrer un json para obtener su longitud (length).

Este es mi código:

```
var parametros = {
        yMin: "0",
        yMax: "300",
        ySteps: "5",
        yLabel: "users",
        xMin: "1",
        xMax: "12",
        xSteps: "11",
        xLabel: "months",
        canvasDiv: canvasId,
        label: "/2011",
        color: "orange",
        data: {
            data0: [120, 65, 85, 111, 131, 160, 187, 180, 205, 146, 64, 212],
            data1: [0, 106, 200, 100, 130, 131, 2, 50, 50, 89, 290, 1],
            data2: [0, 106, 200, 100, 130, 131, 2, 50, 50, 89, 290, 1]
            }
    }
```

y quiero saber el length de

```
data: {
            data0: [120, 65, 85, 111, 131, 160, 187, 180, 205, 146, 64, 212],
            data1: [0, 106, 200, 100, 130, 131, 2, 50, 50, 89, 290, 1],
            data2: [0, 106, 200, 100, 130, 131, 2, 50, 50, 89, 290, 1]
            }
    }
```

para después ejecutar una función en la cual debo enviar como parámetro `data0`, `data1` y `data2`.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿ No te vale `parametros['data']['data0'].length` ?

Comment: Lo que publicaste es un objeto, no un JSON. ¿Estás intentando obtener cuántas propiedades tiene ese objeto?

Answer (score 6):

Entiendo que quieres saber cuantos parámetros tienes data, porque puedes tener "data0", "data1", "data2", "data3", etc.

Te pongo un ejemplo de como sacar cuantos parámetros tiene data:

```js
var parametros = {
        yMin: "0",
        yMax: "300",
        ySteps: "5",
        yLabel: "users",
        xMin: "1",
        xMax: "12",
        xSteps: "11",
        xLabel: "months",
        canvasDiv: "id",
        label: "/2011",
        color: "orange",
        data: {
            data0: [120, 65, 85, 111, 131, 160, 187, 180, 205, 146, 64, 212],
            data1: [0, 106, 200, 100, 130, 131, 2, 50, 50, 89, 290, 1],
            data2: [0, 106, 200, 100, 130, 131, 2, 50, 50, 89, 290, 1]
            }
    }

//Array con las keys del contenido de data
console.log(Object.keys(parametros.data));

//Tamaño del array
console.log(Object.keys(parametros.data).length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.keys(parametros.data).length

Con esto deberías poder sacar la longitud del objeto "data" dentro del objeto "parametros".

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo:

```
let lenghtData = 0
data.forEach( e => {
    lenghtData += 1 
})
console.log( lenghtData );
```

Desde ahí puedes almacenar dicho valor en una variable o lo que te plazca.

Comment: 4 años, 7 meses y 1 hora después te puedo decir, que no es la mejor forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Podrías comentarme cuál es? Quisiera aprenderlo.